# Enabling Apple Pay in Authorize.net & Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, authorize.net, applepay

So I have all the Certificate and PEM setup but Woocommerce instructions are vague at best with where to add this Snippet to allow me to enable the Apple Pay on the Payment Gateway.

add_filter( 'wc_payment_gateway_authorize_net_cim_activate_apple_pay', '__return_true' );

Plugin Settings Configuration
This section is only required for Authorize.Net, CyberSource, and Moneris.

Once your domain has been verified and your PEM file is placed appropriately on the server, you can now enable Apple Pay via a one-line filter, then configure the plugin to enable Apple Pay. To enable Apple Pay, use one of the following snippets:

Authorize.Net

add_filter( 'wc_payment_gateway_authorize_net_cim_activate_apple_pay', '__return_true' );

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add the filter to my functions.php file to add Apple Pay to the plugin.

Comment: any documentation on this? it gives an error => An error occured please try again or try with alternamte method.